# Applying line gradient to line paths in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, json, svg, leaflet

I need to apply some gradient to the SVG stroke on lines created in leaflet map, since the gradient depends on the line direction, I have the following style (based on an example I found):

```
<defs>
    <lineargradient id="NE" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#ff7111" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
    </lineargradient>
    <lineargradient id="NW" spreadMethod="pad" x1="100%" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#ff7111" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
    </lineargradient>
    <lineargradient id="SE" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#ff7111" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
    </lineargradient>
    <lineargradient id="SW" spreadMethod="pad" x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#ff7111" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
    </lineargradient>
</defs>
```

I created a feature.property associated with the LAT-LNG values and already have it on the line paths, however I would like to know how to associate this property to apply the specific SVG style.

I have uploaded [HERE](https://bl.ocks.org/cccruzr/02eaee5c3206f9e5ddb86374a9b6af83) a Gist to reproduce my problem, however couldn't get the .geojson work on bl.ocks.

Hope you guys can help me with a solution.

Comment: gradientTransform might be helpful to you here.

Comment: I solved the problem just putting the code inside the tag: 
`<svg xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; version="1.1"> </svg>`